Reading / Fixing a corrupt parquet file
I have a parquet file, that was being written on by a continuous loop as follows:
    def process_data(self):
        #... other code ...

        with pq.ParquetWriter(self.destination_file, schema) as writer:
            with tqdm(total=total_rows, desc="Processing nodes") as pbar:
                for i in range(0, total_rows, self.batch_size):
                    # ... processing code ...

                    # Create a table from the batched data
                    batch_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
                        [
                            pa.array(node_ids),
                            pa.array(mut_positions),
                            pa.array(new_6mers),
                            pa.array(context_embeddings),
                            pa.array(nonmutation_contexts),
                        ],
                        schema=schema
                    )

                    # Write the batch table
                    writer.write_table(batch_table)

                    # ...

                    pbar.update(len(batch_indices))

This loop was abruptly cut off due to the computer shutting off in the middle of the process.
Now when I try to read the file through pq.read_table, I (expectedly) get an error
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Error creating dataset. Could not read schema from 'data/processed/data_with_embeddings.parquet'. Is this a 'parquet' file?: Could not open Parquet input source 'data/processed/data_with_embeddings.parquet': Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file.

I desperately hope there's a way out of this. Like a workaround. Like losing a few (or more) rows, but saving most of the data. I have searched the web but seemingly there isn't really anything about this, or the existing ones are above my expertise (which might be obvious from my tag use, I apologize in advance).
Is there hope?

Programmatic solution.
So based on documentation.
In order to recover anything you need to have metadata for that anything.
So, since you definitely don't have data for the whole table try reading it by row groups.
Method you can take from doc. Notice constructor of ParquetFile - you can ignore checksum verification.
Brute force.
Open corrupted file in hex viewer (e.g. Notepad++ hex editor). Enjoy puzzle - this might be helpful here. :)

Thank you.
I got pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file. when I tried to construct a ParquetFile instance. I assume appending PAR1 to the end of the file could help this? But before that, I realized that the ParquetFile constructor optionally takes an "external" FileMetaData instance, which has properties that I may be able to estimate (?). Is this possible, or do you think I should just append PAR1 to the parquet file and see what happens? Again, I'm too new to this so apologizing in advance.

okay, I did append PAR1, and what I got is:
OSError: Couldn't deserialize thrift: don't know what type: 

yeah, the manual fixing of file might be really hard to do - I think imputing custom metadata should be a better choice.

From the docs

If the file metadata is corrupt, the file is lost.

and

the biggest issue is placing the file metadata at the end.

Parquet files have their metadata at the end of the file so I fear your file is lost because the footer wasn't written :(
